# Count isn't counting the amount of string items in an array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I just want to count the words in the array using .count but its giving the following error:

error: type mismatch: inferred type is String but (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean was expected
println(sentArr.count(x))

```
**code**:
 

fun main() {
    var sentence = "Bob hit a ball, the hit BALL flew 
     far after it was hit."
    var sentArr = sentence.split(" ")
    var bannedWords = arrayOf("ball")
    
for(x in sentArr){
    println(sentArr.count(x))
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think `count` takes any parameters. It should just be sentArr.count() https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html

Comment: That's so strange. You should be able to count the amount of items on a list of Strings...Kotlin is wierd lol

Comment: You can do that, you just misunderstand how the `count` function works. What are you trying to achieve here? Count the number of items in the list, or count the number of occurrences of each item?

Comment: Also, depending on your actual goals, there might be better way to achieve that. For instance, if you want a map of frequencies, you can probably use groupings instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to count the words in the array, you can simply write `sentArr.size` or `sentArr.count()`. No need for a loop

Answer (score 2):

If I am correctly guessing what you're trying to do, this is what you're looking for:

```
for(x in sentArr){
    println(sentArr.count { it == x })
}
```

This means to count how many of the Strings in the array are the same as `x`.